# Custom field searchable

Tags: workflow, field-update, search, global-search

I have a formula field in the account object and I want to make this field searchable. What should I do?
I saw one method where we have to create a workflow rule and a field update for this. Is this the only way.

Comment: Formula field values do not exist in the database and are calculated on demand (e.g. when querying their value). These therefore are not searchable. You need to explicitly store their equivalent value in the database in a non-formula field, updating this field when the formula would change value. I.e. you essentially have to replace the formula field with a field you explicitly calculate in triggers or flows when the underlying values change.

Comment: @PhilW So doing this way replacing with another field is it possible to make the new field searchable

Comment: When adding a field you can indicate whether it is searchable from what I remember. AFK right now so cannot check.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_custom_object.htm&type=5)?  You'll need to replace the formula field with a text field that is populated by a Flow or Apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Phil, formula fields are not searchable and you need to [make additional fields searchable](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313945&type=1) by using workflow(retiring soon)/flow.

You might want to review and upvote limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiZrUAJ/search-on-formula-fields).